# Opposite of newline in vim

Tags: vim

In vim, is there a command to delete the newline, and all empty space behind the cursor?

Say I stand in the middle of a text in insert mode and press Enter, what command would the reverse what I just did?

A) An example:

```
"some code{ in here }"
```

B) After pressing Enter:

```
"some code{
   in here }"
```

Now pressing backspace will delete one space of the indentation. I would rather have it delete all indentation, and jump back to A.

Can this be done in a command or by doing some remapping to the backspace key?

Comment: In command mode 'u' will undo last action; Not sure if you want something that can delete arbitrary line breaks after the fact though.

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/698/deleting-groups-of-autoindents-in-insert-mode

Answer (score 9):

It's tragic how unknown the `J` command is. It joins lines in normal mode.

In insert mode, you can press `<C-U>` twice; first, it'll delete the indent before the cursor, then it'll join with the previous line. Note that this requires

```
:set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Comment: Thank you, I will practice using J more, it seems like a powerful command to store in muscle memory

Answer (score 5):

did you try `J (uppercase)` ? it will give exactly what you want.

`"some code{` cursor on this line, press<kbd>J</kbd>

`in here }"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do <kbd>ᴇꜱᴄ</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

<kbd>K</kbd> jumps up to the previous line and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> joins the two lines.

However, with properly configured indentation and syntax, a backspace doesn’t just delete a space, it deletes the full previous indentation block.

Comment: You know that with the current edit (and original) it doesn't look like `Esc`, it's `E<some funny character>s` (I'm using Firefox).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I apologize for the invalid edit then *(it sure wasn't my intention)* but it is as 244an says. The `esc` doesn't look like an escape in firefox and `K` doesn't go to the previous line with vim 7.3. The help says about `K`: "Run a program to lookup the keyword under the cursor".

Comment: @244an Your font is missing some characters then. The characters I’m using are “SMALL CAPITAL” Unicode characters.

Comment: @Lieven I’m not using the character `K` but the *keyboard key “K”*. That’s standard convention for denoting keyboard keys. Look on your keyboard: they keys there are labelled with capital letters. That’s why I’m using “Shift” later on

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Fair enough but the vim helpfile doesn't use that standard convention, t uses uppercase characters where shift is implied. All in all, it made me think and as Steve Krug said [Don't make me think](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dont-Make-Think-Usability-Circle-Com/dp/0789723107). We really should seriously discuss this over a pint. ;)

Comment: @Lieven The Vim helpfile doesn’t have a way of marking up keyboard keys. They use a *workaround* to render keystrokes in plain text with minimal formatting. We simply don’t have this restriction here. But I’m always up fror discussing over a pint. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is up one line, to end of that line and just delete. As long as you still are in insert mode it will do the same thing as `J` when deleting at the last position - like most other editors. For me that is the quickest alternative because I'm used to it from other editors.

That is: <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd> (when still in insert mode)

One quick alternative (the VIM-way) is (when still in insert mode):
<kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd> (when still in insert mode)

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> is used in insert mode to enter one normal mode command.)

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use a remapping of the backspace key:

```
inoremap <expr> <bs> getline('.')[:col('.')-2]=~'^\s\+$' ? "<c-u><c-u>" : "<bs>"
```

Note that this mapping **completely overrides** the normal behavior the backspace key. This will only be useful when you don't intend to use its normal behavior. This is not recommended if you can easily access the other options (c-u or J)

However, (as far as I know) there's no way to distinguish between manually added leading white spaces and auto indent. If you use `noexpandtab`, you can edit the regex to only match tabs.

This also does not work in some modes of auto-indent (for example, in block comment in C, vim automatically start a new line starts with `*`)